# How to run a loop inside sh -c

Tags: shell-script, shell, escape-characters, for

I'm having trouble understanding what I need to escape when using `sh -c`.

Let's say I want to run the for loop `for i in {1..4}; do echo $i; done`. By itself, this works fine.
If I pass it to `eval`, I need to escape the `$`: `eval "for i in {1..4}; do echo \$i; done"`, but I cannot make it work for `sh -c "[...]"`:

```
$ sh -c "for i in {1..4}; do echo $i; done"
4

$ sh -c "for i in {1..4}; do echo \$i; done"
{1..4}

$ sh -c "for i in \{1..4\}; do echo \$i; done"
{1..4}

$ sh -c "for i in \{1..4\}\; do echo \$i\; done"
sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected
```

Where can I find more information about this?

Comment: Which shell is linked to your `sh` ?

Comment: `which sh` -> `/bin/sh`; `file /bin/sh` -> `/bin/sh: symbolic link to dash`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The usual wisdom is to define the script (after the `-c`) inside single quotes. The other part you need to use is a shell where the `{1..4}` construct is valid:

```bash
$ bash -c 'for i in {1..4}; do echo $i; done'  # also work with ksh and zsh
```

One alternative to get it working with dash (your `sh`) is to make the expansion on the shell you are using interactively (I am assuming that you use bash or zsh as your interactive shell):

```bash
$ dash -c 'for i do echo $i; done' mysh {1..4}
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 2):

`{1..4}` is a zsh operator, extended from `csh`'s `{x,y}` brace expansion operator now supported by a few other shells, but it's not a POSIX sh operator (until recently, POSIX actually even *required* `echo {1..4}` to output `{1..4}`).

Even in zsh or other shells that now support `{x..y}`, it's not the best way to do loops that increment an integer variable as you end up allocating a list of all the values (OK here for only 4 but doesn't scale well). `for i in $(seq 4)` (`seq` being *not* a standard command) has the same problem, in addition to relying on the current value of `$IFS`.

In ksh93, bash, zsh, using:

```
for (( i = 1; i <= 4; i++ )); do
  printf '%s\n' "$i"
done
```

Is generally regarded as better. It also allows negative values, and a better control on how the index is incremented.

The `{x..y}` approach has the advantage of allowing loops on several ranges, or looping on letters, or with padding (though with variations depending on the shell and version thereof) though:

```
for i in {1..5} {9..12} x{0..3} {f..p} {001..0010}; do
  ...
done
```

In `zsh`, see also:

```
i=; repeat 4 printf '%s\n' $((++i))
```

In POSIX `sh`, you'd do:

```
i=1; while [ "$i" -le 4 ]; do
  printf '%s\n' "$i"
  i=$(( i + 1 ))
done
```

Or:

```
sh -c '
  i=1; while [ "$i" -le 4 ]; do
    printf "%s\n" "$i"
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
  done'
```

From within another Bourne/rc/fish like shell if you need to have a new `sh` invocation run that loop.

Of course, here, you could also do:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4; do
  printf '%s\n' "$i"
done
```